# State mutated by getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to write a getter that returns a simple number from state, decremented by 1

```
const getters = {
  getCurrentView: state => {
    return types.PAGES_OBJECT[state.currentViewNum]
  },
  getCurrentViewNum: state => {
    return state.currentViewNum--
  }
};
```

However this actually mutates the state.

I have tried assigning it to a `var`, but it appears that `var` becomes a direct reference to state.

How do I do this, without mutating state?

Comment: Are you looking for this? `return state.currentViewNum - 1`

Comment: @ChrisG Yeh.... I'll go hide now

Comment: Don't forget to delete the question ;)

Comment: @ChrisG Can't. Got an answer now. Lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't `x--` equivalent to `x = x - 1`?

The `--` operator is mutating your object.

return `state.currentViewNum - 1` instead

Comment: Yeah. I'll go cry now

Comment: Any idea why var gets passed a reference tho ?

Comment: The ++ operator increments a variable and it returns the value of the variable, perhaps for this reason it returns a reference to your object.

Comment: Im sure returning `state.currentViewNum - 1` will circumvent the issue.

Comment: yeah it did, hence my first comment :) Will accept when time elapses